# where can I set that the tree in the explorer in eclipse when opened is expanded exactly as it was before last exit?

Tags: eclipse

where can I set that the tree in the explorer in eclipse when opened is expanded exactly as it was before last exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's answered here:

[How to save the "Package Explorer" in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816170/how-to-save-the-package-explorer-in-eclipse)